# ASP.net Report Viewer way to check whether report viewer has rendered

Tags: asp.net, webforms

I am running the report viewer on one of my pages and I want to display loading icon while the Report Viewer is loading (since there is a significant delay between the control and the report viewer render), but I do not have a way to tell when the report viewer has loaded so I can stop rendering the loading icon. Does anyone know a callback function or a way to tell the rest of the page that report viewer has finished loading?

Comment: Can you show some code to demonstrate what you're trying to accomplish? You can use $(document).ready(function () { setTimeout("checkLoaded()",150); }); to sniff out specific control ID's in the DOM, but i'm not exactly sure what you're looking to accomplish so you'll need to determine what you want to do in checkLoaded() function.

Comment: Essentially I just need a way to determine that report viewer has rendered. If I know that the alert viewer has rendered I can stop the loading icon on report viewer completed render

Comment: the doc ready function will run when the DOM is fully loaded, however if you have some late binding controls you know want to load in last or as late as possible, you'll need to force a short delay before performing any operations on these objects.

Comment: So I am not rendering any documents yet, the control starts the Report Viewer and I need to know when it has finished rendering, not an individual document created.

Comment: In this case, "document" doesn't refer to any documents produced by the report control, it refers to the DOM (document object model). The doc ready function will fire once all of the DOM objects (controls, markup etc) have finished loading on the page. Try this if you're new to the DOM https://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-2-Core/introduction.html